# Vuetify: Dependent v-select based on selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a codepent - example:
https://codepen.io/rasenkantenstein/pen/qBdZepM

The user should choose a country and eventually only select the cities belonging to a country. However, there's an array behind the data of the people. How can I tell Vue(tify) to alter only those items from the currently edited row?

```
    changeCity(index, country) {
     //How can I filter the cities here for each person?
     let result = this.cities.filter(city => {
       return city.country == country
     })
     console.log(result)
     //this works on all fields... ? --> this.cities = result
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should filter the cities based on the person country, inside your v-select, like this:

```
:items="cities.filter(c => c.country === person.country)"
```

Comment: Quite easy if you grasped the concept... Thank you!